# Python OpenCV - filtering out contours, that are not nearby

Tags: python, opencv, pycharm, radius

I'm trying to get my program to show me only the centre of the road, by filtering out the rest.
I have started by finding width and length for every rectangle in the centre of the road and filtering out the rest.

Problem:
Some rectangles that are not in the centre of the road are still visible, as they are within the width and length of the other rectangles which are in the centre of the road.

My idea:
Running a for-loop for every rectangle shown which will:
Using a small radius on one end of the rectangle to see if another rectangle is inside that radius, if so, show that rectangle,
-> if not:
use the other end of the rectangle with the same radius and see if another rectangle is inside that radius, if so, show that rectangle,
-> if both of these statements are false: do not show the rectangle, which has been used to find another rectangle nearby.

My idea is to filter out every other rectangle that has been found, which is not in the centre of the road, as every rectangle in the centre of the road is close to one another (has at least 1 rectangle nearby).
Basically every rectangle that is not within the centre of the road has a bigger distance to another rectangle, which is why I think i can work with radius or distance here, but that is just my idea.
Now I have run out of ideas, I would need some help to make it work, as I am not only new to OpenCV but to Python as well. 
I want this code to work not only for this road, but other roads where the image looks the same.

Original picture:
[This is the original picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zy3y.png)
Picture with the rectangles left:
[This is the picture with the rectangles left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3sQp.png)

EDIT!: I was told I can work with scipy.spatial.KDTree to find neighbors.

this is my code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Read image

image = cv2.imread('Resources/StreckeUni.png')

# Grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# show image
cv2.imshow('Gray', gray)
cv2.waitKey(0)

# Adjust Contrass and brightness
alpha = 50  # Kontrast (0-100)
beta = 0  # Helligkeit (0-100)
adjusted = cv2.convertScaleAbs(gray, alpha=alpha, beta=beta)

# Bild anzeigen
cv2.imshow('Contrast', adjusted)
cv2.waitKey(0)

#  find Canny Edges
edged = cv2.Canny(adjusted, 30, 200)

# Use Blur
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(edged, (3, 3), 0)

# find Conturs
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(blur, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

# show img
cv2.imshow('Canny Edges', blur)
cv2.waitKey(0)

# show number of contours
print("Anzahl der Konturen = " + str(len(contours)))

# draw rectangles
for cnt in contours:
    rect = cv2.minAreaRect(cnt)
    box = cv2.boxPoints(rect)
    box = np.int0(box)

    if rect[1][0] > rect[1][1]:
        laenge = rect[1][0]
        breite = rect[1][1]
    else:
        laenge = rect[1][1]
        breite = rect[1][0]

    if 13.9 < laenge < 25.1 and 3.2 < breite < 7.7:
        cv2.drawContours(image, [box], -1, (0, 255, 0), 1)

# show final pic
cv2.imshow('Rectangles', image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: I’ve spent some time taking your rectangle detection in the original image and turning the detected rectangles ordered from the bottom of image to top into a sequence of adjacent markers around the track, successfully ignoring outliers. Are you interested in having this code as an answer? It’s not exactly pretty code, but it works for this track image. I didn’t use kdtree because of the gaps in the centre-line markers - you have to try to connect to a rectangle in each direction which is more complex than simply the two nearest rectangles.

Comment: Hey, sounds great, can I have the code? Maybe it will help me see things, I haven't thought of before :-)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spent a while trying to use your detected rectangles for the centre line (with the odd noise of others off-centre) to get to the sequence around the track.

I started by slightly tweaking your code to save the detected rectangles to normalise them to always wider than high, and save to a json file

```
# from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62430766/python-opencv-filtering-out-contours-that-are-not-nearby

import cv2
import numpy as np
import json
import scipy.spatial
import math

IMAGE="track"

# Read image

image = cv2.imread(IMAGE+".png")

# Grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# show image
#cv2.imshow('Gray', gray)
#cv2.waitKey(0)

# Adjust Contrass and brightness
alpha = 50  # Kontrast (0-100)
beta = 0  # Helligkeit (0-100)
adjusted = cv2.convertScaleAbs(gray, alpha=alpha, beta=beta)

# Bild anzeigen
#cv2.imshow('Contrast', adjusted)
#cv2.waitKey(0)

#  find Canny Edges
edged = cv2.Canny(adjusted, 30, 200)

# Use Blur
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(edged, (3, 3), 0)

# find Conturs
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(blur, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

# show img
#cv2.imshow('Canny Edges', blur)
#cv2.waitKey(0)

# show number of contours
print("Anzahl der Konturen = " + str(len(contours)))

possiblecentres = []

# draw rectangles
for cnt in contours:
    rect = cv2.minAreaRect(cnt)
    box = cv2.boxPoints(rect)
    box = np.int0(box)
#    print(f"{rect=} {box=}" )
    if rect[1][0] > rect[1][1]:
        print( f"gt {rect[2]}")
        laenge = rect[1][0]
        breite = rect[1][1]
        angle = rect[2]
        tag="gt"
    else:
        print( f"lt {rect[2]}")
        laenge = rect[1][1]
        breite = rect[1][0]
        angle = rect[2]+90
        tag="lt"
    rect1 = [[rect[0][0],rect[0][1]],[laenge,breite],angle]
    if 13.9 < laenge < 25.1 and 3.2 < breite < 7.7:
        cv2.drawContours(image, [box], -1, (0, 255, 0), 1)
#        possiblecentres.append(rect)
        possiblecentres.append(rect1)
#        print( rect)

# show final pic
cv2.imshow('Rectangles', image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
#cv2.destroyAllWindows()
open( "centres.json","w").write(json.dumps(possiblecentres,indent=4))
cv2.imwrite(IMAGE+"_ol.png",image)
```

Then I wrote code to take this json file and connect up the rectangles.

I considered using e.g. kdtree to find nearest neighbours but it isn't that simple because there are gaps so connection isn't always to the nearest two neighbours. Instead I tried to look for the closest neighbour in a direction 'positive' in the direction of the rectangle and 'negative' in the opposite direction.

Three phases of processing:

First phase is simple to calculate the centre of the thin ends - will use these as a line segment for parametric line calculations of intersection.

Second phase goes through all the segments trying to find the best connected neighbours - this uses the angle and direction of each rectangle to calculate the distance along those angles from the focussed rectangle to all the other rectangles, rejecting ones at too steep an angle, and selecting those closest in each direction - I tried a metric calculated from the length of path and angle, choose the minimum for the pos/neg directions. The complications with this were that the detected rectangles jitter around a bit and some are parallel, so there's a little fudge here and there to try disambiguate (in particular the denom threshold 30 is set to get this image to work, you might need to tune that. If the image were higher resolution this would probably be simpler. The intersection logic is the most complicated part. The detected rectangles are from top to bottom of the image, and their direction can be either way, so the intersect has to handle this. Also when interections are within the line segment that needs special handling because it isn't so obvious how to calculate the path length and angle difference between them.

This search for nearest neighbours uses a brute force search against all the others - it works perfectly fast enough that there was no reason to bother trying to optimise by only comparing with "nearest" rectangles.

The search for positive/negative neighbours will happily bridge gaps - if there were noise rectangles near these gaps that could cause problems, but happily that's not the case in your image :-) My idea with the metric was to try and prefer connections at smaller angles in order to resist noise - your image doesn't really exercise that.

Example of image overlaid with all connections is the first image below.

Third phase now all the pos/neg connections are known is to go through building sequences. If one node has a pos or neg connection to another, it is "connected" if that other node has a reciprocal positive or negative connection back. Accepting only reciprocated connections means the outliers are rejected - they become one-rectangle sequences. Note adjacent rectangles can be validly in opposite directions so e.g. a positive connection to another node can be validly reciprocated by either a positive or a negative connection from that node.

Because the starting node can (hopefully does) have both pos and neg connections, I keep a stack of connections still to check. The starting node's positive connection is put on the stack first and only pulled off once the negative side can't make any more connections, then it is inserted into the start of the sequence - this handles where there isn't a connected loop, so the sequence is still correct.

Then it shows you the connected sequences :-) See second image below.

Apologies the code isn't exactly refined/pretty, but it works for this image - I'll be interested to hear if it works with other track images.

Coded using Python 3.8.3 and opencv 4.2 on Windows/AMD64

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import json
import scipy.spatial
import math

# set to true to produce copious debugging printout while trying to connect
DEBUG = False
# set to true to display image after each iteration of trying to connect
STEP = False
# the image to draw over
TRACK = 'track_ol.png'

def dist(x1,y1,x2,y2):
    return math.sqrt((x2-x1)*(x2-x1)+(y2-y1)*(y2-y1))
    
# normalise ang to +/-pi
def normalise(ang):
    while ang<-math.pi:
        ang += 2.0*math.pi
    while ang>math.pi:
        ang -= 2.0*math.pi
    return ang

# returns the parametric distance of the intersection of l1 and l2 in terms of l1
def intersect(l1,l2):
    if DEBUG:
        print( f"{l1=}" )
        print( f"{l2=}" )
    x1,y1=l1[0][0],l1[0][1]
    x2,y2=l1[1][0],l1[1][1]
    x3,y3=l2[0][0],l2[0][1]
    x4,y4=l2[1][0],l2[1][1]
    if DEBUG:
        print( f"{x1=} {y1=}" )
        print( f"{x2=} {y2=}" )
        print( f"{x3=} {y3=}" )
        print( f"{x4=} {y4=}" )
    denom = (x1-x2)*(y3-y4)-(y1-y2)*(x3-x4)
    xc1,yc1=(x1+x2)/2.0,(y1+y2)/2.0
    xc2,yc2=(x3+x4)/2.0,(y3+y4)/2.0
    if DEBUG:
        print( f"{denom=}" )
    if abs(denom)<30.0: # this is a bit of a fudge - basically prefer finding parallel lines to slighly divergent ones
        # parallel
        # work out distance between the parallel lines https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line
        dist1 = abs((y2-y1)*x3-(x2-x1)*y3+x2*y1-y2*x1)/math.sqrt(dist(x1,y1,x2,y2))
        if DEBUG:
            print( f"{dist1=}" )
        if dist1>30.0:
            if DEBUG:
                print( f"Parallel rejected dist {dist1=}" )
            return None,None
        # work out the centres of the line joining centres of l1 and l2 - going to use the line joining these centres
        intx,inty = (xc1+xc2)/2.0, (yc1+yc2)/2.0        # and if angle of intersection would be too greate
        pathlength = dist(xc1,yc1,xc2,yc2)
#        t = dist(xc1,yc1,intx,inty)/dist(x1,y1,x2,y2)
#        u = -dist(xc2,yc2,intx,inty)/dist(x1,y1,x2,y2)
        # choose the x or y which is most different
        if abs(y2-y1)>abs(x2-x1):
            t = (inty-y1)/(y2-y1)
        else:
            t = (intx-x1)/(x2-x1)
        if abs(y4-y3)>abs(x4-x3):
            u = (inty-y3)/(y4-y3)
        else:
            u = (intx-x3)/(x4-x3)
        ang1 = math.atan2(y2-y1,x2-x1)
        ang2 = math.atan2(yc2-yc1,xc2-xc1)
        # choose the smaller change
        ang = normalise(ang2-ang1)
        if abs(ang)>0.5*math.pi:
            pathlength = -pathlength
            ang = normalise(math.pi-ang)
            
        if DEBUG:
            print( f"Parallel {xc1=} {yc1=} {xc2=} {yc2=}" )
            print( f"Parallel {intx=} {inty=}" )
            print( f"Parallel {pathlength} {t=} {u=} {ang=} {ang1=} {ang2=}" )
        if abs(ang)>0.5*math.pi:
#            print( f"Rejected ang {ang=}" )
            return None,None
#        if abs(ang) >0.5*math.pi:
#            t = 1.0-t
        if DEBUG:
            print( f"Parallel {pathlength} {t=} {u=} {ang=}" )
        return pathlength,ang
        
    # work out the intersection https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line%E2%80%93line_intersection
    t = ((x1-x3)*(y3-y4)-(y1-y3)*(x3-x4))/denom
    u = -((x1-x2)*(y1-y3)-(y1-y2)*(x1-x3))/denom
    intx,inty = x1+t*(x2-x1),y1+t*(y2-y1)
    pathlength = dist(xc1,yc1,intx,inty)+dist(intx,inty,xc2,yc2)

    if DEBUG:
        print( f"{intx=} {inty=}" )
    # get the raw angle of l1 and l2
    
    # if t is <0, turn ang1 by 180 to point towards the intersection
    ang1 = math.atan2( y2-y1,x2-x1 )
    ang2 = math.atan2( y4-y3,x4-x3 )
    # get the angle of line from centre of l1 to centre of l2
    angc = math.atan2( yc2-yc1,xc2-xc1 )
    # decide if centre l2 is "forwards" (in the direction l1 points) of centre of l1 - used only when there is an intersection within one of them
    # so sign of pathlength can be set correctly
    # MUST do this before normalising ang1 to point to the intersection and ang2 to point away
    if abs(normalise(angc-ang1)) < 0.5*math.pi:
        l1forwards = True
    else:
        l1forwards = False
    if DEBUG:
        print( f"{l1forwards=} {angc=} {ang1=}" )
    # now normalise ang1 to point towards the intersection
    # NOTE if either intersection is within either line, ang1/ang2 normalisation doesn;t matter
    # because the smaller difference angle will be used.
    if t < 0.0:
        ang1 = normalise(ang1+math.pi)
    # we want ang2 going away from the intersection, so it u is positive reverse the angle
    # now normalise ang2 to point away the intersection
    if u > 1.0:
        ang2 = normalise(ang2+math.pi)
    # check for intersection within l1 or l2
    if 0.0 <= t <= 1.0:
        # internal to l1
        if 0.0 <= u <= 1.0:
            # this is internal to both l1 and l2
            raise Exception( "This should never happen because it means the blobs overlap!")
        else:
            # internal only to l1
            # find the smallest angle of intersection
            if abs(normalise(ang2-ang1))<abs(normalise(math.pi-(ang2-ang1))):
                ang = normalise(ang2-ang1)
                if DEBUG:
                    print( "t norev" )
            else:
                ang = normalise(math.pi-(ang2-ang1))
                if DEBUG:
                    print( "t rev" )
            if abs(ang)>0.25*math.pi:
                if DEBUG:
                    print( f"Rejected1 {ang=} {ang1=} {ang2=}" )
                return None,None
            pathlength = pathlength if l1forwards else -pathlength
    else:
        # not internal to l1
        if 0.0 <= u <= 1.0:
            # internal only to l2
            if abs(normalise(ang2-ang1))<abs(normalise(math.pi-(ang2-ang1))):
                ang = normalise(ang2-ang1)
                if DEBUG:
                    print( "u norev" )
            else:
                ang = normalise(math.pi-(ang2-ang1))
                if DEBUG:
                    print( "u-rev" )
            if abs(ang)>0.25*math.pi:
                if DEBUG:
                    print( f"Rejected2 {ang=} {ang1=} {ang2=}" )
                return None,None
            pathlength = pathlength if l1forwards else -pathlength
        else:
            # this is external to both l1 and l2 - use t to decide if forwards or backwards
            ang = normalise(ang2-ang1)
            pathlength = pathlength if t >= 0.0 else -pathlength
        
#    ang = math.atan2(y2-y1,x2-x1)-math.atan2(y4-y3,x4-x3)
    if DEBUG:
        print( f"{pathlength=} {t=} {u=} {ang=} {ang1=} {ang2=}" )
    if abs(ang)>0.5*math.pi:
        if DEBUG:
            print( f"Rejected ang {ang=}" )
        return None,None
    return pathlength,ang
        
#cv2.waitKey(0)
#cv2.destroyAllWindows()

possiblecentres = json.loads(open( "centres.json","r").read() )

# phase 1 - add the x/y coord of each end of the rectangle as the ends of a line segment
for i,candidate in enumerate(possiblecentres):
    candidate.append(0) # usecount    
    xc,yc,dx,dy,angle = candidate[0][0],candidate[0][1],candidate[1][0]/2.0,candidate[1][1]/2.0,candidate[2]*math.pi/180.0
    x1,y1 = xc-dx*math.cos(angle),yc-dx*math.sin(angle)
    x2,y2 = xc+dx*math.cos(angle),yc+dx*math.sin(angle)
    candidate.append(((x1,y1),(x2,y2))) #centre-endpoints

image = cv2.imread(TRACK)

# phase 2 - for each blob, find closest pos/neg blob
for i,candidate in enumerate(possiblecentres):
    posintersect,pospt,posang,len1 = 1e10,None,None,None
    negintersect,negpt,negang,len1 = 1e10,None,None,None
    l1 = candidate[4]
    if DEBUG:
        print( f"\n\n\n===================================\n{i=} {l1=}" )
        print( f"{candidate=}" )
    
    for j,other in enumerate(possiblecentres):
        if i==j:
            continue
        l2 = other[4]
        if DEBUG:
            print( f"\n============\n{j=} {l2=}" )
            print( f"{other=}" )
        
        pathlen,ang = intersect(l1,l2)
        if pathlen is None:
            continue
        metric =pathlen*pathlen*math.exp(abs(ang))
        if metric > 100000000:
            if DEBUG:
                print( f"Rejected metric {metric=}" )
            continue
#        print( f"{pathlen=} {ang=} {metric=}" )
        # find closest intersection in +ve direction
        if pathlen>=0.0 and metric<posintersect:
            posintersect,pospt,posang,len1 = metric,j,ang,pathlen
            if DEBUG:
                print( "POS updated")
        if pathlen<0.0 and metric<negintersect:
            negintersect,negpt,negang,len1 = metric,j,ang,pathlen
            if DEBUG:
                print( "NEG updated")

    if DEBUG:
        print( i,candidate,posintersect,pospt,posang,negintersect,negpt,negang )
    print( f"{i=} {pospt=} {negpt=}" )
#    foundconnections[i] = 0
    possiblecentres[i].append(((posintersect,pospt,posang,len1),(negintersect,negpt,negang,len1)))
#    cv2.line(image,(int(candidate[4][0][0]),int(candidate[4][0][1])),(int(candidate[4][1][0]),int(candidate[4][1][1])),(255,255,255))
    if STEP:
        image = cv2.imread(TRACK)
    thisrect = (candidate[0],candidate[1],candidate[2])
    box = cv2.boxPoints(thisrect)
    box = np.int0(box)
    cv2.drawContours(image, [box], -1, (255, 255, 255), 1)

    if pospt is not None:
        cv2.line(image,(int(candidate[0][0]),int(candidate[0][1])),(int(possiblecentres[pospt][0][0]),int(possiblecentres[pospt][0][1])),(255,0,0))
    if negpt is not None:
        cv2.line(image,(int(candidate[0][0]),int(candidate[0][1])),(int(possiblecentres[negpt][0][0]),int(possiblecentres[negpt][0][1])),(0,255,0))
    if STEP:
        cv2.imshow('Rectangles', image)
        if cv2.waitKey(0)==113:
            break

# finally phase 3 - for each blob's connections, match up with another blob that reverses that connection
# This eliminates odd blobs that aren't recipricolly connected to the things they connect to
sequences = [] # each entry in this list is a sequence of indexes into possiblecentres
todos = list(range(len(possiblecentres)))
stacktochecks = []  # this should never have more than two items on it - and the first one is only removed once the circuit is complete
while True:
    if stacktochecks:
        print( f"{stacktochecks=}" )
        print( f"{sequences[-1]=}" )
        # continued sequence
        startpt = stacktochecks.pop()
        if stacktochecks:
            # we are on the outbound leg - for a fully-connected start point there's a non-empty stack which is the other connection from that starting element
            sequences[-1].append(startpt)
        else:
            # stack is empty so insert new points at the start of this sequence - this ensures the sequence on the list is consecutive even if the outgoing sequence didn't come back here
            sequences[-1].insert(0,startpt)
        print( f"continuing from {startpt=}" )
    else:
        if sequences:
            print( f"FINISHED {sequences[-1]=}" )
        if len(todos)==0:
            break
        # new sequence
        startpt = todos.pop(0)
        sequences.append([startpt])
        print( f"starting from {startpt}" )
    nextpos = possiblecentres[startpt][-1][0][1]
    nextneg = possiblecentres[startpt][-1][1][1]
    print( f"{nextpos=} {nextneg=}" )
    if nextpos is not None:
        if nextpos in todos:
            # hasn't been used yet
            if startpt == possiblecentres[nextpos][-1][0][1]:
                print( f"pos match1 pushing {nextpos}" )
                stacktochecks.append(nextpos)
                todos.remove(nextpos)
            elif startpt == possiblecentres[nextpos][-1][1][1]:
                print( f"pos match2 pushing {nextpos}" )
                stacktochecks.append(nextpos)        
                todos.remove(nextpos)
            else:
                #
                todos.remove(nextpos)
                pass
    #            burp3
        else:
            if nextpos in sequences[-1]:
                # already in sequences, so we closed the loop!
    #            burp1
                pass
            else:
                # not in current sequence and not in todos - that's weird, but end the sequence
                pass
#                burp2
    #            pass
    if nextneg is not None:
        if nextneg in todos:
            # hasn't been used yet
            if startpt == possiblecentres[nextneg][-1][0][1]:
                print( f"neg match1 pushing {nextneg}" )
                stacktochecks.append(nextneg)
                todos.remove(nextneg)
            elif startpt == possiblecentres[nextneg][-1][1][1]:
                print( f"neg match2 pushing {nextneg}" )
                stacktochecks.append(nextneg)        
                todos.remove(nextneg)
            else:
                #
                todos.remove(nextneg)
                pass
    #            burp4
        else:
            if nextneg in sequences[-1]:
                # already in sequences, so we closed the loop!
    #            burp5
                pass
            else:
                # not in current sequence and not in todos - that's weird, but end the sequence
                pass
#                burp6
    #            pass

print( f"{sequences=}")

image = cv2.imread(TRACK)

# now display the sequences, and put circles on the startpoints
for i,seq in enumerate(sequences):
    for j,node in enumerate(seq):
        thisnode = possiblecentres[node]
        thisrect = (thisnode[0],thisnode[1],thisnode[2])
        box = cv2.boxPoints(thisrect)
        box = np.int0(box)
        cv2.drawContours(image, [box], -1, (255, 255, 0), 1)
        thisx,thisy = thisnode[0][0],thisnode[0][1]
        if j == 0:
            cv2.circle(image,(int(thisx),int(thisy)),10,(0,127,127),2)
            firstx,firsty = thisx,thisy
        if j > 0:
            # draw a thick line to previous
            cv2.line(image,(int(lastx),int(lasty)),(int(thisx),int(thisy)),(127,127,127),5)
        if j!=0 and j+1==len(seq):
            # this is the connection back to the start
            cv2.line(image,(int(firstx),int(firsty)),(int(thisx),int(thisy)),(127,127,127),5)
        
        lastx,lasty = thisx,thisy

cv2.imshow('Sequences', image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Things that could probably be improved is to tidy up the intersection calculation, for example change my fudge to simply treat the two line segments as parallel using the angle they are at rather than the `denom` value. Now there's a known good answer you could use this to validate that changes aren't breaking anything - it can be quite difficult to detect anomalies in the neightbour detection certainly not easy on the full image if all connections are shown, so I had to step through the detection and focus on the detected connections for a particular rectanlge to understand why the connection was jumping a neighbour, to fix the logic.

Intermediate image after phase 2 showing all the connections - a blue connection is a positive, green is a negative. NOTE many connections are overlaid on top of each other so particularly between adjacent rectangles you only see the one drawn last.

[image]

Resulting image (with a circle over each start point):

[image]

Here is the long sequence of the track - the numbers are indexes into the centres.json array, Rectangle 0 is at the lowest point in the image (visually) which is connected to 1 and 18 maybe a pixel or two higher up.

[18, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 19, 20, 21, 22, 12, 13, 23, 30, 33, 35, 37, 39, 41, 43, 45, 47, 49, 51, 53, 55, 57, 72, 88, 93, 94, 95, 97, 99, 102, 104, 105, 119, 124, 143, 144, 145, 147, 149, 152, 159, 163, 168, 172, 175, 177, 178, 176, 174, 169, 167, 165, 162, 160, 156, 155, 153, 154, 157, 161, 164, 170, 180, 182, 184, 186, 189, 191, 194, 193, 192, 190, 188, 185, 183, 181, 173, 166, 158, 151, 148, 146, 142, 135, 131, 127, 123, 120, 112, 111, 110, 108, 109, 114, 116, 117, 121, 125, 128, 132, 134, 137, 139, 140, 141, 138, 136, 133, 130, 126, 122, 118, 113, 107, 106, 103, 101, 98, 96, 87, 68, 60, 59, 61, 63, 62, 64, 65, 67, 66, 70, 71, 73, 75, 74, 76, 78, 77, 79, 81, 80, 82, 85, 84, 86, 90, 89, 92, 91, 83, 69, 58, 56, 54, 52, 50, 48, 46, 44, 42, 40, 38, 36, 34, 32, 31, 28, 29, 24, 25, 26, 27, 14, 15, 16, 17]

Next time I setup a scalextric slot car track I'll try taking a picture, see if this code works :-)

Comment: Wow, it took me so long to understand this code, as I am just a beginner, but what you did here is really amazing! Thank you for doing this, may I ask you, how much experience do you have in this field? This looks really advanced, I do not even fully understand it, yet.

Comment: This was mostly trial and error plus persistence - that's why the code is messy. If the rectangles were known very precisely and accurately then the intersection code could be much simpler, but at this image resolution they are (relatively speaking) all over the place. I've done some geomtetry stuff in the past. Using parametric lines (defined by two points) simplifies things like finding intersections without worry about gradient of the line which blows up for vertical lines. Hope it's useful. If I answered your question you can if you want accept my answer and optionally upvote :-)

Comment: This would definitely help, if I had more knowledge in Python, as I am very new, I have to yet try and understand the code. I am right now trying to use a video, in which the cars were having a race, and taking the first frame of the video to find the middle line. Sadly the resolution is even worse when taking the 1st Frame (or any frame even), than just taking a Screenshot, but it would be much better if the program could find the middle line off of the frame. It's very complicated, how you first created a JSON file and then used another code, I've never done something like this before.

Comment: I was hoping it would be much simpler, by just maybe using a for-loop for every contour and finding the nearest neighbor, and if there are neighbors within a certain radius, it would show them, so that the outer contours are not within the given radius and invisible. I am still working on that code. If you had fun with this project, I can send you some videos and my Code snippet, and you can try yourself when you have time and are bored :D

Comment: Thank you - but I've already got plenty to do at the moment :-)

Answer (score 0):

I am posting as a comment, because I don't exactly know what to do with this.
I found this piece of code and thought it should work with mine:

```
    def get_laser_points(image):
        """
        Return centers of laser-points found in the given image as list of coordinate-tuples.
        """
        # get the contour areas for the steppers
        mask = cv2.inRange(image, whiteLower, whiteUpper)
        contours, _ = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
        # compute the center of the contour areas
        centroids = []
        for contour in contours:
            m = cv2.moments(contour)
            # avoid division by zero error!
            if m['m00'] != 0:
                cx = int(m['m10'] / m['m00'])
                cy = int(m['m01'] / m['m00'])
                centroids.append((cx, cy))
                # following line manages sorting the found contours from left to right, sorting
                # first tuple value (x coordinate) ascending
                centroids = sorted(centroids)
        return centroids
```

now that i have some kind of center for every contour, what do i do?